# jquery: select element based on name and ancestor

Tags: jquery

I want to attach a click event to elements that are named "page_chooser", but only if they have an ancestor with id = "posting".

To just get elements named "page_chooser" I do this:

```
$("[name=page_chooser]").click(function() {
```

How can I add the extra ancestor restriction? I want to do this because I use the name "page_chooser" on several webpages, but the click function should be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ancestor selector:

```
$("#posting [name=page_chooser]").on('click', function () {
```

or using delegation in case `page_chooser` elements are loaded asynchronously:

```
$("#posting").on('click', '[name=page_chooser]', function () {
```

Comment: The first example worked perfectly :) I can accept in 10 min.